# mysql alternative regex - return the part of regular expression which matched the sample

Tags: mysql, regex

trying to find a way in mysql how to return the part of regular expression which matched the test string.

regex: `(^123[0-9]+$)|(^9876[0-9]+$)|(^56789012$)`

test string: `123456`

I want to get: `^123[0-9]+$`

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you need a flag to determine which regex matched ?  Not sure what you mean, but in this `^(?:(?:(123)|(9876))[0-9]+|(56789012))$` there are 3 capture groups. I'm guessing that's irrelevant, probably because Mysql doen't know non-capture grouping.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any  comand that can do it

but you can always

do it like this

> ```
> SELECT '123456' REGEXP '(^123[0-9]+$)|(^9876[0-9]+$)|(^56789012$)'
> ```
>
> ```
> | '123456' REGEXP '(^123[0-9]+$)|(^9876[0-9]+$)|(^56789012$)' |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------: |
> |                                                           1 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CASE
> WHEN '123456' REGEXP '^123[0-9]+$' THEN '^123[0-9]+$'
> WHEN '123456' REGEXP '^^9876[0-9' THEN '^9876[0-9'
> WHEN '123456' REGEXP '^56789012$' THEN '^56789012$'
> ELSE
> 'no pattern'
> END
> ```
>
> ```
> | CASE
> WHEN '123456' REGEXP '^123[0-9]+$' THEN '^123[0-9]+$'
> WHEN '123456' REGEXP '^^9876[0-9' THEN '^9876[0-9'
> WHEN '123456' REGEXP '^56789012$' THEN '^56789012$'
> ELSE
> 'no pattern'
> END |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | ^123[0-9]+$                                                                                                                                                                             |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf3ea1adbc2aec1aa52719c1e0dec013)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
SELECT 'the 1st one' as which_regexp WHERE '123456' REGEXP '^123[0-9]+$'
UNION
SELECT 'the 2nd one' as which_regexp WHERE '123456' REGEXP '^9876[0-9]+$'
UNION
SELECT 'the 3rd one' as which_regexp WHERE '123456' REGEXP '^56789012$';
```